# SubProcess in python with git

Tags: python, git, python-2.7

i have a python script that check each git commit and run some test on the given commit.
It does that sequentially . (one commit each time)

I want to be able to run the test on some commit and simultaneity continue to the next commit .

My program looks like this .

```
def start_listen();
   while true:

        //check if there were any commits.//

       if item in (commits):
            test the commit;
```

So i want during the test on some commit to continue to test another commit .

Comment: Sounds like you want to do some kind of parallel processing. You could look into [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)

Comment: Can you give example of what can i do ?

Comment: The documentation for `multiprocessing` module has examples: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html